# Fire simulation won`t be randered

Tags: fluid-simulation, fire

[image]
[image]

Tried to render fire simulation in Cycles, results are above. I added principled volume node to domain cube.

Fire shows up in viewpoint, however does not in rendered image. In viewpoint, fire is shown in both EEVEE, and Cycles. I barely changed output and render setting (only modified solution, folder for rendered files)

Comment: Hi, can you try sending the file.

Comment: i would really love to. however i don`t know how. can i upload the file? or do i need to send it to your email?

Comment: There is a site for that. You can upload it here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/ee582b813c2f41fab54995d6cb4e8b29) this is the file

Comment: what version are you using ?

Comment: i just found the reason, i just made domain cube not shown at rendering in ouliner. i maybe aciddently click the camera button. sorry for my mistake. and thanks for your help

Comment: It's ok, for some reason, I couldn't see the fire even in the viewport, but that would have been mostly because I was using version 2.82.

Comment: i am using 2.92.

Comment: I am 5 versions behind you, no wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: Please click the checkmark button on my answer so we can get this question signed off as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera render button in view layer window is set to "off".